# Start an app where App is not in Applications folder MacOS

Tags: macos, permissions, alias

I am developing an app for MacOS, in which I am trying to run an app outside of the Applications folder. When the App is in the Applications folder the app is starting without a problem.

But when the app is in a custom folder, then the app is saying the it does not have the permission to open.

[image]

In the Sandbox permissions I do not see what I should allow to let the Alias start the original app.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say alias, do you mean bash alias ?

Comment: Hi, actually it turned out that not the alias is the issue. It is the app itself. When I put an app on an external HDD, my app cannot start it. However it can be started from the Finder.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was the bookmarking a file, which had been manually dragged or opened once.

The simple URL saving does not work as second time the system does not know if the user  had opened the file manually or a "robot" tries to open it. So you need to make a bookmark from the first open attempt, something like this:

```
private func getBookmarkData(url: URL) -> [URL: Data]?{
        let data = try? url.bookmarkData(options: NSURL.BookmarkCreationOptions.withSecurityScope, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
        if let data = data{
            return [url: data]
        }
        return nil
    }
```

The returned URL bookmark data needs to be saved instead of the simple URL.

To get back a usable URL and get it open via the application you need to resolve the bookmark, somehow like this:

```
 func getUsablePath() -> String {
    var isStale = false
    let restoredUrl = try? URL.init(resolvingBookmarkData: object_path as Data, options: NSURL.BookmarkResolutionOptions.withSecurityScope, relativeTo: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)
    _ = restoredUrl?.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
    
    return restoredUrl?.path ?? ""
}
```

I hope this helps others to make an app like where the files could be reached and opened from within the app.